# Confused about Scala method calling conventions, specifically the sum function on Seq

Tags: scala, implicit, parentheses

I was playing around with the new Scala IDE (Eclipse 3.6.2 + Scala IDE 2.0.0 [Scala 2.9.0]) and I tried to do something simple like this:

```
(1 to 10).sum
```

That works fine, but I've been doing a lot of Groovy also recently and I automatically wrote:

```
(1 to 10).sum()
```

This second version gives me a compiler error in the IDE with the following message:

> not enough arguments for method sum: (implicit num: Numeric[B])B. Unspecified value parameter num.

I see on the Scala API that there are two versions of sum, one that takes no parameters and one that takes the implicit above.  Do I have to call zero-argument methods without parentheses?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is that **if** you specify a *parameter list* (i.e. use the parens), **then** you **must** specify the parameters in it (or, more accurately, those without defaults).

If you omit the parens on a non-empty parameter list whose parameters are `implicit`, then the compiler can inject them for you (assuming it can find the relevant implicits unabmiguously in your scope: as in your first example)

```
1 to 10 sum
```

If you want to pass in the parameter yourself (there is no need to do so in this example), then you can take advantage of `Predef.implicitly` which basically returns the unabiguous in-scope implicit value (assuming there is one). Their use here would be:

```
(1 to 10).sum(implicitly[Numeric[Int]])
(1 to 10).sum[Int](implicitly)
```

This is particularly important in methods which take more than one implicit parameter, of which you might only wish to override one (you can then use `implicitly` for the others). For example, in **scalaz**

```
aFoldable.sum(implicitly, myMonoid) //uses implicit Foldable but bespoke monoid
```

For your question about the **scaladoc** *use case*; this is a *phantom* entry to show you how to use the (otherwise potentially confusing) method with the implicit parameter list. The existence of this scaladoc entry can be traced to [this notorious question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-histo).

Comment: `scala> (1 to 10).sum(implicitly)
error: ambiguous implicit values: both method conforms in object Predef of type [A]<:<[A,A] and method stringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String] match expected type T`

Comment: I see... so because I read the scaladoc wrong (as @Sciss stated below), there is only version which has an argument and so that triggered the rule that if I'm using parens then I have to specify the parameter. Otherwise, in other cases of the API, if there is a no-arg version, I could use empty parens or no parens.  Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: @plecong - you cannot use empty parens if the method has no parameter lists, but otherwise, yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one version. If you carefully look at the API, the entry that has no parentheses says "[use case]" in the beginning. This is a synthetic duplicate entry in the API docs which is for easier grasping; the use-case entries are basically reduced full entries for some common scenarios. More on this in this question: [Scaladoc [use case]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106817/scaladoc-use-case)

The reason why the second call (...sum()) fails is that although the argument is implicit, it doesn't have a default value. You can only omit arguments inside parentheses when default values are provided. Although this sounds illogical, implicit arguments are treated differently: either you supply them explicitly, then you need to use the parentheses, or you omit them (because an implicit is found in scope), but then you also need to drop the parentheses. This is to facilitate better readability, e.g.

```
def test(fun: Int => Int)(implicit s: String)
```

now you can write `test { i => i }` and not `test(i => i)()` which is awkward.