# Why does Set#map return an Array rather than another Set?

Tags: ruby, collections, set, containers, enumerable

Just ran into `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Set into Array` doing something of the form

```
thingGetterSet.map{|m| m.getThing }.select{|t| t.appropriate? } + appropriateThingsSet
```

It turns out `Set#map` returns an Array, where I expected a Set to map to another Set.

Even if that had returned a set, `Set#select` also returns an Array, where I also expected a Set.

What's going on here?  Why is Ruby imposing a random ordering and allowing duplication on my things that are canonically non-ordered and where I want to prohibit duplication?

Comment: The class `Set` includes the module `Enumerable` to make `Enumerable` instance methods available for use by instances of `Set`. [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) return arrays regardless of the class of their receiver (e.g., arrays, hashes and so on).

Comment: Make your life easier now: switch to [snake case](https://github.com/github/rubocop-github/blob/master/STYLEGUIDE.md#naming).

Comment: Ruby can't possibly know that the result of `Set#map` is a set. For example `Set[1,2,3].map(&:odd?)`

Comment: @max I'm not sure that's the reason, since `map!` is implemented for Set (`x = Set.new([1,2,3]); x.map!(&:odd?)`)

Comment: @spike `map!` mutates the receiver so there it makes sense that it actually returns a set. `.map` by definition iterates across an object and returns an array.

Comment: `set.dup.map!(&:odd?) == Set[true, false]` is a pretty entertaining way to see if a set contains both even and odd numbers though.

Comment: @spike, if you look though a list of `Enumerable` methods you will see that there are no `bang!` methods and none of them modify their receiver. Many classes that `include Enumerable` implement custom versions of some enumerable methods, sometime  because it is desired to return a different class of object (e.g, [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-select)) but more often to improve performance (e.g., [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map)).

Comment: @max: "Ruby can't possibly know that the result of `Set#map` is a set." – Of course, it can. For example, in Smalltalk and Scala, it knows just that. It's trivial to do in Ruby, as well: just override all `Enumerable` methods in all subtypes of `Enumerable`! Et voila: type-preserving collection methods. "For example `Set[1,2,3].map(&:odd?)`" – The result of that is obviously `Set[true, false]`, no problem there.

Answer (score 4):

There are, in general, two different styles of collection operation libraries:

- *type-preserving*: that is what you expect in your question
- *generic* (not in the "parametric polymorphism sense" but the standard English sense of the word) or maybe "homogeneous"

Type-preserving collection operations try to preserve the type exactly for operations like `select`, `take`, `drop`, etc. that only take existing elements unmodified. For operations like `map`, it tries to find the closest super type that can still hold the result. E.g. mapping an `IntSet` to `String` can obviously not result in an `IntSet`, but only in a `Set`. Mapping an `IntSet` to `Boolean` could be represented in a `BitSet`, but I know of no collections framework that is clever enough to actually do that.

Generic / homogeneous collection operations always return the same type. Usually, this type is chosen to be very general, to accommodate the widest range of use cases. For example, In .NET, collection operations return [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable), in Java, they return [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)s, in C++, they return iterators.

Until very recently, it was only possible to implement type-preserving collection operations by duplicating all operations for all types. For example, the Smalltalk collections framework is type-preserving, and it does this by having every single collections class re-implement every single collections operation. This results in a lot of duplicated code and is a maintenance nightmare. (It is no coincidence that many new object-oriented abstractions that get invented have their first paper written about how it can be applied to the Smalltalk collections framework. See [*Traits: Composable Units of Behaviour*](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf) for an example.)

To my knowledge, [the Scala 2.8 re-design of the collections framework](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) ([see also this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724807/2988)) was the first time someone managed to create type-preserving collections operations while minimizing (though not eliminating) duplication. However, [the Scala 2.8 collections framework was widely criticized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722726/2988) as being overly complex, and it has required constant work over the last decade. In fact, it actually lead to a complete re-design of the Scala documentation system as well, just to be able to [hide the very complex type signatures that the type-preserving operations require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4107029/2988). But, [this still wasn't enough](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/818), so the collections framework was [completely thrown out and re-designed *yet again* in Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/introduction.html). (And this re-design took several years.)

So, the answer to "why isn't the Ruby collections framework type-preserving" is quite simple, actually: because Ruby was created in 1993, and we (by that I mean the programming community at large) didn't figure out how to properly do it until 2019, 26 years later.

Also note that Scala's implementation relies heavily on static typing. Not only on static typing but on compile-time type-level programming, compile-time type-level introspection and compile-time type-level metaprogramming. These are not *essential*, but they *do* mean that you cannot simply copy their solution to Ruby. For example, Scala will use *type classes* and *implicit search* to figure out that the best possible match for

```scala
IntSet(1, 2, 3).map(_.toString)
//=> val res: Set[String] = Set("1", "2", "3")
```

is a `Set[String]` *at compile-time*. In Ruby, you could obviously still run the same search algorithm, although it would be *much slower* because you need to run it at runtime, over and over and over again for every single time you run `map`. It would be slower, but it would be possible: it's just an algorithm, if you can run it at compile time, then you can run it at runtime as well. BUT! The algorithm needs the return type of the block as one of its arguments! In Scala, this is inferred at compile time. How do you know that in Ruby?

But even in Scala, it is sometimes not possible to find a good match, e.g. here:

```scala
val m = Map(1 → "one", 2 → "two", 3 → "three")

m.map { case (k, v) ⇒ s"$k $v" }
//=> val res: Iterable[String] = List("1 one", "2 two", "3 three")
```

So, the best possible static type Scala could find is `Iterable`, which is actually the very top of the Scala collections hierarchy, and the best possible runtime type Scala could find is `List`, which is actually the "go-to" collection type in Scala, similar to `Array` in Ruby. In other words, this is actually Scala saying "I give up, man."

There is also another wrinkle, in that type-preserving collections operations challenge what we consider to be part of the contract of certain operations. For example, most people would argue that the cardinality of a collection should be invariant under `map`, in other words, `map` should map each element to exactly one new element and thus `map` should never change the size of the collection. But, what about this hypothetical code with a type-preserving Ruby collections framework:

```rb
Set[1, 2, 3].map(&:odd?)
#=> Set[true, false]
```

There are also some other interesting cases, where I don't even know what the return type should be in a type-preserving collections framework, for example, what about `Range`s or `IO` streams:

```rb
(1..1000).map(&:odd?)
(1..1000).select(&:odd?)

File.open('bla').map(&:upcase)
```

Because of all of this, the designers of Ruby chose to have *homogeneous* collections operations in Ruby: *every* collection operation *always* returns an `Array`.

Well. Okay. Except sometimes they *do* choose to override them. E.g. in `Hash`, the filtering operations `select`, `reject`, etc. actually *do* return a `Hash`. But note that this is a recent change, and has in fact an interesting history:

- In Ruby 1.8 (and possibly earlier), [`Hash#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select) returned an `Array`, but [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-reject) returned a `Hash`!
- In Ruby 1.9, this was changed so that [both return a `Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject).
- However, `find_all`, which is defined in `Enumerable` as an alias to `select`, is *still to this day* not overridden in `Hash`, and thus it returns an `Array`!
- On the other hand, the newly-introduced `filter`, which is *also* defined as an alias to `select` in `Enumerable`, *is* overridden in `Hash` to return a `Hash`.

So, the Ruby designers chose simplicity (no code duplication, no complex type computation at runtime, all operations always return arrays so there are no surprises like in the example above where `map` changes the size of the set, etc.) over correctness, and made the Ruby collection operations homogeneous instead of type-preserving. But then they also chose pragmatism over purity and sprinkled some small number of type-preserving overrides here and there.

So, the fact that `Set#map` returns an `Array` should not be terribly surprising because that's what *every single other class in the collections framework* does as well. Changing this *only* for `Set#map` is not a good idea, IMO. *If* we do this, it should be done for *all* implementors of `map`. But that is a major breaking change, and thus will have to wait until Ruby 3 at the earliest. (Actually, matz has said that he wants to avoid breaking changes in Ruby 3.) But even changing *only* `map` for all implementors is strange, *if* we do this, it should be done for *all* operations. This is a major research task, and is thus much too late for Ruby 3, so this would have to wait until at least Ruby 4.

What we *can* argue about, however, is whether `Array` is the right choice for the universal collection type. You might notice that other similar frameworks choose a very general type: .NET has `IEnumerable`, Java has `Stream`, C++ has iterators. The equivalent in Ruby would be `Enumerator`. Maybe, `Enumerator` should be the type that is returned by all collections operations. For example, if you `map` over an infinite set, the result will again be infinite, but it will be an `Array`, which means it needs an infinite amount of memory!

This brings us back to pragmatism, though: in the majority of use cases, an `Array` is more useful than an `Enumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments said, the issue here is that Set includes `Enumerable` as the provider of a bunch of methods including `map`. This is a language design decision, so the best answer I can give is to point you to the developer's mailing list. This is an interesting thread from a few years ago: "[Hash#select return type does not match Hash#find_all](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13795)", particularly "[[Ruby trunk Bug#13795] Hash#select return type does not match Hash#find_all](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/82331)".

I saw a few reasons in the thread for not re-implementing `map` and others in `Set`:

1. This is counter to the benefit of having a general purpose Enumerable, causing extra implementation work for classes that include that module as they'd have to re-implement a bunch of methods (though this wasn't the major reason).
2. There are uses of `map` where it's unclear that keeping the original data structure is a good idea. For example with `:odd?` in the comments, also there's an example in the mailing list thread of

   ```
   {}.map {|k, v| "#{k}-#{v}"}
   ```

   which wouldn't work returning a `Hash`.
3. There are other Standard Library classes, like `Range` and `IO`, where keeping their type post-map wouldn't make sense, so it's more consistent for the default behavior to return an array.