# IndexedSeq[Int] vs Array[Int]

Tags: scala

Coming from a Java background I am learning Scala and the following has me very confused. Why is the type returned different in these two (very similar but different) constructs, which vary only in how the source collection was build -

```
  val seq1: IndexedSeq[Int] = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i
```

vs.

```
  val seq2: Array[Int] = for (i <- Array(1, 2, 3)) yield i
```

Please do point to me the right literature so that I can understand the core fundamentals at play here.

Comment: When you map something, it makes sense to preserve the type

Comment: Another thing to get used to in Scala is that most of the time you can just let it infer types, reducing the possibility for human error, e.g., `val seq1 = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i` and `val seq2 = for (i <- Array(1, 2, 3)) yield i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, in general, two different styles of collection operation libraries:

- *type-preserving*: that is what you are confused about in your question
- *generic* (not in the "parametric polymorphism sense" but the standard English sense of the word) or maybe "homogeneous"

Type-preserving collection operations try to preserve the type exactly for operations like `filter`, `take`, `drop`, etc. that only take existing elements unmodified. For operations like `map`, it tries to find the closest super type that can still hold the result. E.g. mapping over an `IntSet` with a function from `Int` to `String` can obviously not result in an `IntSet`, but only in a `Set`. Mapping an `IntSet` to `Boolean` could be represented in a `BitSet`, but I know of no collections framework that is clever enough to actually do that.

Generic / homogeneous collection operations always return the same type. Usually, this type is chosen to be very general, to accommodate the widest range of use cases. For example, In .NET, collection operations return [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable), in Java, they return [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)s, in C++, they return iterators, in Ruby, they return arrays.

Until recently, it was only possible to implement type-preserving collection operations by duplicating all operations for all types. For example, the Smalltalk collections framework is type-preserving, and it does this by having every single collections class re-implement every single collections operation. This results in a lot of duplicated code and is a maintenance nightmare. (It is no coincidence that many new object-oriented abstractions that get invented have their first paper written about how it can be applied to the Smalltalk collections framework. See [*Traits: Composable Units of Behaviour*](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf) for an example.)

To my knowledge, [the Scala 2.8 re-design of the collections framework](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) ([see also this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724807/2988)) was the first time someone managed to create type-preserving collections operations while minimizing (though not eliminating) duplication. However, [the Scala 2.8 collections framework was widely criticized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722726/2988) as being overly complex, and it has required constant work over the last decade. In fact, it actually lead to a complete re-design of the Scala documentation system as well, just to be able to [hide the very complex type signatures that the type-preserving operations require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4107029/2988). But, [this still wasn't enough](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/818), so the collections framework was [completely thrown out and re-designed *yet again* in Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/introduction.html). (And this re-design took several years.)

So, the simple answer to your question is this: Scala tries as much as possible to preserve the type of the collection.

In your second case, the type of the collection is `Array`, and when you `map` over an `Array`, you get back an `Array`.

In your first case, the type of the collection is `Range`. Now, a `Range` doesn't actually have elements, though. It only has a beginning and an end and a step, and it produces the elements on demand while you are iterating over it. So, it is not that easy to produce a new `Range` with the new elements. The `map` function would basically need to be able to "reverse engineer" your mapping function to figure out what the new beginning and end and step should be. (Which is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, or in other words impossible.) And what if you do something like this:

```scala
val seq1: IndexedSeq[Int] = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield scala.util.Random.nextInt(i)
```

Here, there isn't even a well-defined step, so it is actually impossible to build a `Range` that does this.

So, clearly, mapping over a `Range` cannot return a `Range`. So, it does the next best thing: It returns the *most precise super type of `Range`* that can contain the mapped values. In this case, that happens to be `IndexedSeq`.

There is a wrinkle, in that type-preserving collections operations challenge what we consider to be part of the contract of certain operations. For example, most people would argue that the cardinality of a collection should be invariant under `map`, in other words, `map` should map each element to exactly one new element and thus `map` should never change the size of the collection. But, what about this code:

```scala
Set(1, 2, 3).map { _ % 2 == 0 }
//=> Set(true, false)
```

Here, you get back a collection with *fewer* elements from a `map`, which is only supposed to *transform* elements, not *remove* them. But, since we decided we want type-preserving collections, and a `Set` cannot have duplicate values, the two `false` values are actually the same value, so there is only one of them in the set.

[It could be argued that this actually only demonstrates that `Set`s aren't collections and shouldn't be treated as collections. `Set`s are *predicates* ("Is this element a member?") rather than collections ("Give me all your elements!")]

Answer (score 5):

this happens because construction:

```
for (x <-someSeq) yield x
```

is the same as:

```
someSeq.map(x => x)
```

`for () yield` is just syntactic sugar for `flatMap`/`map` function.

As we know `map` function doesn't change type of object-container, it changes elements inside container.
So, in your example `1 to 10` has a type `Range.Inclusive` which extends `Range`, and `Range` extends `IndexedSeq`. Mapped `IndexedSeq` has the same type `IndexedSeq`.

`for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i` the same as `(1 to 10).map(x => x)`

In second case: `for (i <- Array(1, 2, 3)) yield i` you have an `Array`, and mapped `Array` type also `Array`.

`for (i <- Array(1, 2, 3)) yield i` the same as `Array(1, 2, 3).map(x => x)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the right literature would be *Scala for the Impatient* by Cay Horstmann. The first edition is a little outdated but it's held up pretty well. The book is a fairly easy read almost to the end (I admit I don't quite understand lexical parsers or actors, but that's probably on me not Horstmann).

One of the things that Horstmann's book explains early on is that although you can use `for` like in Java, it can actually do much more sophisticated things. As a toy example, consider this Java procedure:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Integer> squaresMod10 = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            squaresMod10.add(i * i % 10);
        }
        for (Integer j : squaresMod10) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
    }
```

If you're using Java 8 or later, your IDE's probably advising you that you "can use functional operators." NetBeans rewrote it thus for me:

```
        squaresMod10.forEach((j) -> {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        });
```

In Scala, you can use "functional operations" for both the `i` and `j` loops in this example. Rather than fire up IntelliJ just for this, I'll use the local Scala REPL on my system.

```
scala> (1 to 10).map(i => i * i % 10)
res2: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1, 0)

scala> (1 to 10).map(i => i * i % 10).toSet
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = HashSet(0, 5, 1, 6, 9, 4)

scala> for (j <- res3) System.out.print(j + " ")
                                          ^
       warning: method + in class Int is deprecated (since 2.13.0): 
Adding a number and a String is deprecated. Use the string interpolation `s"$num$str"`
0 5 1 6 9 4
```

In Java, what would you be going for with `seq1` and `seq2`? With a standard `for` loop in Java, you're essentially guiding the computer through the process of looking at each element of an ad hoc collection one by one and performing a certain operation on it.

Lambdas like the one NetBeans wrote for me still become If and Goto constructs at the JVM level, just like regular `for` loops in Java, as do a lot of what Horstmann calls "`for` comprehensions" in Scala. Either way, you're delegating the nuts and bolts of how exactly that happens to the compiler. In other words, you're not micro-managing.

However, as your `seq2` example shows, it's still possible to wrap collections unnecessarily.

```
scala> 1 to 10
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10

scala> res5 == seq1
res6: Boolean = true

scala> Array(1, 2, 3)
res7: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> res7 == seq2
res8: Boolean = false
```

Okay, that didn't quite go the way I thought it would, but my point stands: in this vacuum, it's unnecessary to wrap `1 to 10` into another `IndexedSeq[Int]` and it's unnecessary to wrap an `Array[Int]` into another `Array[Int]`. Your `for` "statements" are merely wrapping unnamed collections into named collections.