# Why does type inference chooses only most specific type of the target reference when looking at implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, type-inference, typeclass

Consider the following simple code to create a typesafe equals. This first section allows me to create an `Identity` typeclass for any type.

```
scala> trait Equals[A] { def equal(a1 : A, a2 : A) : Boolean }
defined trait Equals

scala>  sealed trait Identity[A] {
     | def value : A
     | def ===(b : A)(implicit e : Equals[A]) = e.equal(value, b)
     | }
defined trait Identity

scala> implicit def ToIdentity[A](a : A) = new Identity[A] { val value = a }
ToIdentity: [A](a: A)java.lang.Object with Identity[A]
```

So, if I create a typeclass for `Equals[Int]`, I should now be able to use my typesafe equals:

```
scala> implicit val EqualsInt = new Equals[Int] { def equal(i1 : Int, i2 : Int) = i1 == i2 }
EqualsInt: java.lang.Object with Equals[Int] = $anon$1@7e199049

scala> 1 === 2
res1: Boolean = false

scala> 1 === 1
res2: Boolean = true

scala> 1 === 1D
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(1.0)
 required: Int
       1 === 1D
             ^
```

OK, so far so good. What happens if I now create an `Equals[Any]`?

```
scala> implicit val EqualsAny = new Equals[Any] { def equal(a1 : Any, a2 : Any) = a1 == a2 }
EqualsAny: java.lang.Object with Equals[Any] = $anon$1@141d19

scala> 1 === 1D
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(1.0)
 required: Int
       1 === 1D
             ^
```

But then if I tell the compiler that my type is an `Any`, rather than an `Int`...

```
scala> (1 : Any) === 1D
res6: Boolean = true
```

So my question is *"why is the compiler not considering **all** of the types which 1 logically has?"*

That is, my understanding was that a reference of type `Int` logically has the types `Int`, `AnyVal` and `Any`. Anyway, I explored a little more, assuming the issue was something to do with covariance. I changed my definition of `Identity`:

```
scala> sealed trait Identity[+A] {
     | def value : A
     | def ===[B >: A : Equals](b : B) = implicitly[Equals[B]].equal(value, b)
     | }
defined trait Identity
```

This time I got the error:

```
scala> 1 === 1D
<console>:10: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Equals[AnyVal]
       1 === 1D
         ^
```

So if I create an `Equals[AnyVal]`, then this also works:

```
scala> implicit val EqualsAnyVal = new Equals[AnyVal] { def equal(a1 : AnyVal, a2 : AnyVal) = a1 == a2 }
EqualsAnyVal: java.lang.Object with Equals[AnyVal] = $anon$1@67ce08c7

scala> 1 === 1D
res4: Boolean = true
```

So here I assume the issue is with the non-contravariance of `Equals`. So I try again (but without creating an `Equals[AnyVal]`):

```
scala> trait Equals[-A] { def equal(a1 : A, a2 : A) : Boolean }
defined trait Equals

scala> 1 === 1D
res3: Boolean = true
```

So, I can sort of see what the typer is doing here. But **my question looks like this**: why is the typer not asking the question (for my first example):

1. 1 is an `Int`; with the implicits in scope I can create an `Identity[Int]` and then use the `===` method. But this does not work because the argument is not an `Int`. Try again considering the alternate types for 1.
2. 1 is an `AnyVal`; with the implicits in scope, I can create an `Identity[AnyVal]` and then use `===`. But this does not work because, although the argument is an `AnyVal`, there is no implicit `Equals[AnyVal]` in scope. Try again considering the alternate types for 1.
3. 1 is an `Any`; with the implicits in scope, I can create an `Identity[Any]` and then use `===`. This works because both  the argument is an `Any` and there is an `Equals[Any]` in scope.

Why does the type-inference only consider the strictest type of 1 (i.e. Int)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing here is prioritized implicit conversion, added in Scala 2.8.

As per the [Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) *(pdf)*, Section **7.2**:

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter’s type, a most speciﬁc one will be chosen using the rules
>   of static overloading resolution (§6.26.3).

This is also the mechanism that underpins `CanBuildFrom` behaviour in [2.8 collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-histo).

Comment: Could you expand on this, possibly with reference to the language spec?

Comment: As for why this makes sense: Imagine what happened if you would always convert to the most general type...

Comment: @Raphael - but my point being that you would choose the most specific and, then, if that did not result in a successful outcome, try the next most specific. On the mailing lists, Martin Odersky's answer basically says "it is this way because to do otherwise would be too computationally expensive"

Comment: Hope you didn't object to me linking to your *other* question here :)