# incredible implicit Array conversion in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit

According to Scaladoc, there is no method named `map` in `Array` class, but there is an implicit function `implicit def intArrayOps (xs: Array[Int]): ArrayOps[Int]` defined in `scala.Predef`. So you can apply `map` on `Array(1,2,3,4)` if you like. But What I am confused about  is that the `map` result is of type `Array[Int]`, not `ArrayOps[Int]`. Here is my test:

```
scala> val array = Array(1,2,3,4)
array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> array.map(x => x)
res18: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res18.isInstanceOf[Array[Int]]
res19: Boolean = true

scala> res18.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Int]]
warning: there wre 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res20: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste the REPL session rather than join a screenshot. It allows search-engine indexation and helps people with impaired sight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It indeed returns an array, as intended and as is convenient, there is no reason you would need an ArrayOps, it is intended only to provide extra methods to arrays. The doc is wrong.

The routine is actually not implemented in ArrayOps. As most collection methods, it is inherited from TraversableLike. And you see two map methods in the doc:

```
def map [B] (f: (T) ⇒ B): ArrayOps[B]
def map [B, That] (f: (T) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Array[T], B, That]): That
```

Only the second one exists (inherited from TraversableLike). It is intended to allow implementation of map in just one place (traversable like) while allways giving the best possible behavior. For instance, a String is a of Seq[Char], if you map with a function from character to character, you get a String, but if you map from collection to say Int, the result cannot be a String and it will just be a Seq. This is explained in much detail in the paper [fighting the bit rot with types](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2009/2338/pdf/09005.OderskyM.2338.pdf).

However, this makes for a very complex signature, which does not reflect the simplicity of using the method, and makes very poor documentation most of the time (you normally would have to chase to which CanBuildFrom in implicit scope would work). This was discussed in [this most famous scala question of stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722726/754787). So the tool scaladoc was extended so that a simpler entry, corresponding to intended usage, may appear. If you look at the [source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.scala#L151) of `GenTraversableLike`, where the routine is introduced, you will see the following in the scaladoc for map (and a similar one in many methods)

```
@usecase def map[B](f: A => B): $Coll[B]
```

Subtypes add in their doc `@define Coll <className>`, and map (among others) appears with the simplified signature, marked [Use case]. In the [source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/branches/2.9.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.scala?rev=25548#L32) of `ArrayOps`, there is a `@define Coll ArrayOps` where it should be `Array`.

Comment: Note : The bug is now fixed (Scala 2.10)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REPL with the -Xprint:typer option to see what's going on. Here is the output of the map method, reformatted for easier reading:

```
$ scala -Xprint:typer

scala> Array(1,2,3,4).map(x => x)
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
// some lines deleted
private[this] val res0: Array[Int] =
  scala.this.Predef.intArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1, 2, 3, 4))
   .map[Int, Array[Int]]
     (( (x: Int) => x ))
     (scala.this.Array.canBuildFrom[Int](reflect.this.Manifest.Int));
```

So simplifying for package names here is what happens:

```
intArrayOps(Array(1,2,3,4)) // converts to ArrayOps
  .map[Int, Array[Int]]     // calls map with parameter lists below
    ((x:Int) => x)          // pass identity function as fisrt param
    (Array.canBuildFrom[Int]// pass builder for Array[Int] as second param
      (Manifest.Int))       // pass class manifest for Int
```

1. So there is indeed a conversion to `ArrayOps` (first line). It returns `ArrayOps[Int]`.
2. The `ArrayOps.map[Int, Array[Int]]` method is then called on it. Then as didierd explain, the original signature for `map` - not the simplified signature - indicates that the return type inferred will be `Array[Int]`