# What are standard Scala monads other than Option?

Tags: scala, monads

`Option` monad turns pretty much a facility some times in Scala. Are there any other monads in Scala standard library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can work this out by looking up the tell-tale `flatMap` in the [API index](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-f). It gives:

```
FilterMonadic 
Stream 
StreamWithFilter 
TraversableMethods 
Iterator 
ParIterableLike 
ParIterableLike 
ParIterableViewLike 
TraversableLike 
WithFilter 
MonadOps 
TraversableProxyLike 
TraversableViewLike 
LeftProjection 
RightProjection 
Option 
WithFilter 
Responder 
Zipped 
ControlContext
Parser
```

Answer (score 12):

Luigi's answer is correct, but not very informative, IMHO.

All collections *can* implement the monad interface, but the signature for `flatMap` in them is not a monad's flatMap. They'll act like monads most of the time, though. Almost all of the classes listed by Luigi are related to collections.

`LeftProject` and `RightProject` refers to `Either`. Basically, `Either` is not a monad, but if you "project" one of the sides, then that side acts pretty much like an `Option` monad.

`Parser` is a monad, which forms the basis of parser combinators.

I admit I do not recognize `ControlContext`. I wonder if it is related to continuations (which are monads as well).

Comment: What do you intend by "the signature for flatMap in them is not a monad's flatMap" ? Are you referring to the implicit machinery ?

Comment: @paradigmatic, yes. See the Tony Morris rant [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist/1735694#1735694).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the links to three sources files from Scalaz:

- [Pure.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Pure.scala)
- [Bind.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Bind.scala)
- [Monad.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala)

Take a look at instance declarations. That might give you an idea about what types from the standard library satisfy the monadic interface.

Comment: OP is not referring to scalaz