# Why does Scala's Traversable have two copyToArray methods with slightly different types?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm learning about collections, and I just noticed these two methods in the [`Traversable` docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable).  What's the point of the first one?  The second one seems to include it.

```
copyToArray        (xs: Array[A], start: Int, len: Int): Unit
copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int, len: Int): Unit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the second subsumes the first.  However, the first doesn't actually exist.  If you look closer at the docs you'll see the words `[use case]`:

```
abstract def copyToArray(xs: Array[A], start: Int, len: Int): Unit
[use case] Copies elements of this collection to an array.
```

A `[use case]` in the Scala API shows a simplified form of the signature.  This gives the "typical" use in a way that isn't so scary to new Scala programmers who might otherwise be confused by the crazy type signatures.

You see the same thing with many other methods, including `map` (in which the `CanBuildFrom` stuff is hidden):

```
abstract def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): CC[B]
[use case] Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this collection.

def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], B, That]): That
Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this collection.
```

To read an old post where Martin Odersky discusses the issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728140/247985).

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a scaladoc artifact.

```
$ scala29
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val c = List(1,2,3)
c: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> c.copyToArray

def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B]): Unit                         
def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int): Unit             
def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int, len: Int): Unit
```

[This year's docs are much nicer.](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable)