# Scalaz Lost in Disjonction

Tags: scala, scalaz, either

I try to transphorm `Seq[\/[String,A]]` to `\/[String,Seq[A]]`

After some research a find the sequenceU method.
But I'm unable to use it, I think by cause of a bad import.

```
import scalaz.syntax.id._
import scalaz.Monoid
import scalaz.ValidationNel
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
```

Maybe I'm not importing an implicit `Traversable as Applicative`

The compiler error message is

```
value sequenceU is not a member of Seq[scalaz.\/[String,A]]
```

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757668/334519)—this is a good question but a duplicate.

Comment: So if I understand (I'm not very good with English), I should use under-type like List Vector ..?

Comment: Err.. since when did I get the power to close a question all by myself? I expected the normal 5 votes to close thingy!

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders