# How to convert a Seq[Reader[E, A]]) into a Reader[E, Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

Here is my actual solution

```
  private def transpose[E, A](readers : Seq[Reader[E, A]]) : Reader[E, Seq[A]] =
    Reader { e: E => readers.map { r => r(e) } }
```

Is there a more straightforward solution with scalaz (maybe with an existing combinator) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This operation is essentially `sequence`:

```
import scalaz.Reader, scalaz.std.list._, scalaz.syntax.traverse._

def transpose[E, A](readers: List[Reader[E, A]]): Reader[E, List[A]] =
  readers.sequenceU
```

In general if `M` has a `Traverse` instance and `N` is a monad, you can transform `M[N[A]]` into an `N[M[A]]` in this way (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358892/334519) for some additional details).

Note that `sequence` won't work with `Seq`, since Scalaz doesn't provide a `Traverse` instance for `Seq` (although it does for `List`, `Vector`, etc.). You can write your own, but I'd suggest [not doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24757668/334519).

(As a footnote, the `U` at the end of `sequenceU` here is just part of a hack to help out Scala's type inference—see my blog post [here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/) for some background.)

Comment: I didn't know that I can use `sequence` with a monad that has a type constructor with 2 types. Thanks !

Comment: `sequenceU` doesn't have the expected return type : `G.M[List[G.A]]`

Comment: @YannMoisan What do you mean? In this case `List` _is_ the `G.A`.

Comment: My bad, it is just a false negative in my IDE (InteliiJ).