# How to combine sequence of Kleisli

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given a method that return a `Kleisli` given a parameter

```
def k[A, B, C](a: A) : Kleisli[Future, B, Option[C]] = ???
```

I want to write a combinator that deals with a sequence of this parameter

```
def ks[A, B, C](as: Seq[A]) : Kleisli[Future, B, Seq[C]] = Kleisli[Future, B, Seq[C]] {
  ctx => Future.sequence(as.map(a => k(a).run(ctx))).map(_.flatten)
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def k[A, B, C](a: A): Kleisli[Future, B, Option[C]] = ???

def ks[A, B, C](as: List[A]): Kleisli[Future, B, List[C]] =
  as.traverseU(k[A, B, C]).map(_.flatten)
```

Note that I'm using `List` instead of `Seq` since Scalaz doesn't provide a `Traverse` instance for `Seq` (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24757668/334519) for some discussion of why it doesn't).

This is one of the big advantages of using `Kleisli` in the first place—if `F` has an `Applicative` instance, then so does `Kleisli[F, In, ?]` for any `In`. In this case that means that you can use `traverse` instead of manually sequencing with `map` and `Future.sequence`.

---

Update: want to get super-fancy here? Probably not, but just in case, you could actually take the abstraction one last step and move the context of the return type into the context of the `Kleisli`:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type FutureOption[x] = OptionT[Future, x]
type FutureList[x] = ListT[Future, x]

def k[A, B, C](a: A): Kleisli[FutureOption, B, C] = ???

def ks[A, B, C](as: List[A]): Kleisli[FutureList, B, C] =
  Kleisli.kleisliMonadTrans[B].liftMU(
    ListT.fromList(as.point[Future])
  ).flatMap(k[A, B, C](_).mapK[FutureList, C](_.toListT))
```

This allows us to map, etc. directly over the result type while ignoring the fact that we're getting that result in a list in a future after applying the `Kleisli` to an input value.

Concretely:

```
import scala.util.Try

def k(s: String): Kleisli[FutureOption, Int, Int] = Kleisli[FutureOption, Int, Int] { in =>
  OptionT(Future(Try(s.toInt + in).toOption))
}

def ks(as: List[String]): Kleisli[FutureList, Int, Int] =
  Kleisli.kleisliMonadTrans[Int].liftMU(
    ListT.fromList(as.point[Future])
  ).flatMap(k(_).mapK[FutureList, Int](_.toListT))
```

And then:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Await

scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> Await.result(ks(List("1", "2", "a", "3")).run(0).run, 1.second)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

And the punchline:

```
scala> val mapped = ks(List("1", "2", "a", "3")).map(_ + 1)
mapped: scalaz.Kleisli[FutureList,Int,Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> Await.result(mapped.run(0).run, 1.second)
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

Should you actually do this? Again, probably not, but it works, and it is kind of cool to be able to map way into a complex computation like this.

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck with `as.traverseU(k)` and this compilation error Error:(40, 24) not enough arguments for method traverseU: (implicit G: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative,scalaz.Kleisli[scala.concurrent.Future,Nothing,Option[Nothing]]])G.M[List[G.A]].
Unspecified value parameter G.
    as.toList.traverseU(k).map(_.flatten)
                       ^