# How to combine option with Kleisli

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli

Given a method

```
def f[A, B, C](a: A) : Kleisli[Future, B, C] = ???
```

I need a combinator working with an `Option[A]`

My first try was :

```
def g[A, B, C](a: Option[A], default: => C) = a match {
  case Some(a) => save(a)
  case None => Kleisli[Future, B, C] { _ => Future.successful(default) }
}
```

But after reading [How to combine sequence of Kleisli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487123/how-to-combine-sequence-of-kleisli), I came up with a better version :

```
def g[A, B, C](a: Option[A], default: => C) : Kleisli[Future, B, C] = 
  a.traverseU(f[A, B, C]).map(_.getOrElse(default))
```

Any idea to improve ?

Comment: That looks fine to me. You could also use `fold` on the `a` directly and lift `default` into a `Kleisli` for the empty side, but that's not likely to end up any nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the idea suggested in comment by @TravisBrown.

```
def g[A, B, C](a: Option[A], default: => C) : Kleisli[Future, B, C] =
  a.fold(Future(default).liftKleisli[B])(f)
```

Readability is maybe better.