# Why is there no Functor instance for Array in Scalaz

Tags: arrays, scala, functor, scalaz

It looks like `scalaz` provides a `Functor` instance for `List` but does not provide it for `Array` (or `Seq`).

```
scala> val fa = Functor[Array]
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[Array]
       val fa = Functor[Array]
                       ^
scala> val fl = Functor[List]
fl: scalaz.Functor[List] = scalaz.std.ListInstances$$anon$1@20c4b59

scala> val fl = Functor[Seq]
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[Seq]
       val fl = Functor[Seq]
                       ^
```

Why is that ? Aren't they functors ?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757668/334519) for some discussion of the `Seq` case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scalaz requires that objects follow the laws for `Functor`s. It also prescribes to the "everything immutable" philosophy of code construction. That said, `Array` is mutable, so they wouldn't create a `Functor` instance for it. `Seq` on the other hand is an abstract interface and it is unknown what the "correct" data type will be. That is, for `Seq` how to know which underlying object to return and therefore not violate any laws?

Comment: Why is `Functor` required to be immutable ? Which laws does the mutability break ?

Comment: @Michael no laws requires immutability. The spirit of what is trying to be achieved and the direction the people behind Scalaz would like others to go requires immutability.

Comment: got it, thank you. I should probably use `ImmutableArray`.