# How to explain Map.map result

Tags: scala, collections

When I look a the `Map.map` scaladoc, I can see

```
map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]
```

But the simple following code doesn't return a `Map`

```
scala> Map("answer" -> 42).map { case(k, v) => v }
res40: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(42)
```

Can you explain ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/203968

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1724530/203968

Comment: Does someone have a link for the @extempore slide about how the scaladoc use cases are lies?

Comment: @som-snytt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiJycy6dFSQ#t=514

Comment: @GabrielePetronella https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jh94gowim0#t=682 "it's in the ill-kinded fiction section" is the one I attended, really good theater. Also, paulp shows us what Santa's elves wear after xmas winds down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaladocs are simplified, if you want to see the full signature you have to expand and click on show full signature and you'll see that the real one is this:

```
def map[B, That](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], B, That]): That
```

Which allows to return a `That` which can be a `Map` but also a `List`.

Comment: What is a "`That`"?  A quick Google didn't reveal anything (likely because "that" is too common a word).  Is it an explicit supertype of a `List` or a `Map`?  Or some sort of generic abstraction?  If I see `That` in a scaladoc, what can I infer about the type?

Comment: Don't be confused by the word, `That` here is a type parameter, it could have been named `T`, or `FVG` or wathever, in this context it simply denotes the return type of the `map`. To make a simpler example `def someMethod[T](value: T): T = value`, here you can say that this methods returns a `T` because `T` is the return type specified in the signature, I could have called `That` if I wanted to: `def someMethod[That](value: That): That = value`

Comment: Gotcha, but then what types can `That` actually be in this case?  I don't immediately see any bounds defining what types `That` can be.  Put another way, how is `That` different than `AnyRef` here?

Comment: Although the type in unconstrained there's an implicit `CanBuildFrom` used to specify whether a type can be build from another, the first type parameter is the from part (in this case we are mapping a `Map[A, B]` and the third parameter is the collection we want to end up with (in the method is `That` in this question in particular it's a `List`). [This blog post](http://www.dotkam.com/2012/05/08/scala-fun-with-canbuildfrom/) explains the `CanBuildFrom` in more details, there are anyway a lot of resources on the matter.

Comment: "Simplified" implies a transformation that preserves some sort of correctness. Scaladocs aren't simplified; they're just wrong. `Map[B]` can't even be a type. It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I agree, I was being generous calling it simplified.

Comment: I don't understand the full signature. Why it's `f: ((A, B)) ⇒ B` instead of `f: ((A, B)) ⇒ C`

Comment: @YannMoisan the scaladoc is flawed, you shouldn't eve look at it, it's better o look at the source dode, this is the actual signature: `def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you need key-value pairs to build Maps.

```
scala> Map("answer" -> 42).map { case(k, v) => (k, 43) }
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(answer -> 43)
```