# Deciphering one of the toughest scala method prototypes (slick)

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

Looking at the `<>` method in the following scala slick class, from http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.ToShapedValue, it reminds me of [that iconic stackoverflow thread about scala prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist).

```
def <>[R, U](f: (U) ⇒ R, g: (R) ⇒ Option[U])
(implicit arg0: ClassTag[R], shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, T, U, _]):
MappedProjection[R, U]
```

Can someone bold and knowledgeable provide an articulate walkthrough of that long prototype definition, carefully clarifying all of its type covariance/invariance, double parameter lists, and other advanced scala aspects?

This exercise will also greatly help dealing with similarly convoluted prototypes!

Comment: You start. There's a few people who care about that one specifically, but not many. So try an explanation, and where you get stuck, probably others will pitch in.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, let's take a look:

```
class ToShapedValue[T](val value: T) extends AnyVal {
  ...
  @inline def <>[R: ClassTag, U](f: (U) ⇒ R, g: (R) ⇒ Option[U])(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, T, U, _]): MappedProjection[R, U]
}
```

The class is an `AnyVal` wrapper; while I can't actually see the `implicit` conversion from a quick look, it smells like the "pimp my library" pattern. So I'm guessing this is meant to add `<>` as an "extension method" onto some (or maybe all) types.

`@inline` is an annotation, a way of putting metadata on, well, anything; this one is a hint to the compiler that this should be inlined. `<>` is the method name - plenty of things that look like "operators" are simply ordinary methods in scala.

The documentation you link has already expanded the `R: ClassTag` to ordinary `R` and an `implicit ClassTag[R]` - this is a "context bound" and it's simply syntactic sugar. `ClassTag` is a compiler-generated thing that exists for every (concrete) type and helps with reflection, so this is a hint that the method will probably do some reflection on an `R` at some point.

Now, the meat: this is a generic method, parameterized by two types: `[R, U]`. Its arguments are two functions, `f: U => R` and `g: R => Option[U]`. This looks a bit like the functional `Prism` concept - a conversion from `U` to `R` that always works, and a conversion from `R` to `U` that sometimes doesn't work.

The interesting part of the signature (sort of) is the `implicit shape` at the end. `Shape` is described as a "typeclass", so this is probably best thought of as a "constraint": it limits the possible types `U` and `R` that we can call this function with, to only those for which an appropriate `Shape` is available.

Looking at [the documentation for`Shape`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.Shape), we see that the four types are `Level`, `Mixed`, `Unpacked` and `Packed`. So the constraint is: there must be a `Shape`, whose "level" is some subtype of `FlatShapeLevel`, where the `Mixed` type is `T` and the `Unpacked` type is `R` (the `Packed` type can be any type).

So, this is a type-level function that expresses that `R` is "the unpacked version of" `T`. To use the example from the `Shape` documentation again, if `T` is `(Column[Int], Column[(Int, String)], (Int, Option[Double]))` then `R` will be `(Int, (Int, String), (Int, Option[Double])` (and it only works for `FlatShapeLevel`, but I'm going to make a judgement call that that's probably not important). `U` is, interestingly enough, completely unconstrained.

So this lets us create a `MappedProjection[unpacked-version-of-T, U]` from any `T`, by providing conversion functions in both directions. So in a simple version, maybe `T` is a `Column[String]` - a representation of a `String` column in a database - and we want to represent it as some application-specific type, e.g. `EmailAddress`. So `R=String`, `U=EmailAddress`, and we provide conversion functions in both directions: `f: EmailAddress => String` and `g: String => Option[EmailAddress]`. It makes sense that it's this way around: every `EmailAddress` can be represented as a `String` (at least, they'd better be, if we want to be able to store them in the database), but not every `String` is a valid `EmailAddress`. If our database somehow had e.g. "http://www.foo.com/" in the email address column, our `g` would return `None`, and Slick could handle this gracefully.

`MappedProjection` itself is, sadly, undocumented. But I'm guessing it's some kind of lazy representation of a thing we can query; where we had a `Column[String]`, now we have a pseudo-column-thing whose (underlying) type is `EmailAddress`. So this might allow us to write pseudo-queries like 'select from users where emailAddress.domain = "gmail.com"', which would be impossible to do directly in the database (which doesn't know which part of an email address is the domain), but is easy to do with the help of code. At least, that's my best guess at what it might do.

Arguably the function could be made clearer by using a standard `Prism` type (e.g. the one from Monocle) rather than passing a pair of functions explicitly. Using the implicit to provide a type-level function is awkward but necessary; in a fully dependently typed language (e.g. Idris), we could write our type-level function as a function (something like `def unpackedType(t: Type): Type = ...`). So conceptually, this function looks something like:

```
def <>[U](p: Prism[U, unpackedType(T)]): MappedProjection[unpackedType(T), U]
```

Hopefully this explains some of the thought process of reading a new, unfamiliar function. I don't know Slick at all, so I have no idea how accurate I am as to what this `<>` is used for - did I get it right?

Comment: I can say just one thing. Wow.

Comment: This, BTW, is one of the great things about a powerful, expressive, strong, static type system: you can tell just by looking at the types what a method does, no need to look at the documentation, let alone the source code, heck, you don't even need the *name*!

Comment: yes that seems accurate to me :) Btw was wondering why the `Option` return type was present. Now wondering what does slick in case of a None