# How to understand List::map declaration in scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections

I just looked at the `List::map` method declaration and was kind of perplexed by its complication. Here is how it looks:

```
final override def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = {
```

Well, I understand what `implicit` is (as far as I got, the type class based on trait `CanBuildFrom` will be automatically introduced by the compiler, if in scope). But what is `That` supposed to mean here?

I understand `map(f: A => B)` as a functorial thing that maps each function `f: A => B` to a function between corresponding monadic values `List(A)` and `List(B)`. So I expected to see the return type to be `List[B]`.

BTW, that's what we actually have in the case of `Option`.

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
```

Both `List` and `Option` are monads. What's is the trick with `List`?

Comment: related: [Is the Scala 2.8 collections library a case of “the longest suicide note in history”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist)

Comment: `That` is just a type parameter.  They could have chosen `C`, or `T`, or whatever.  `That` is often chosen for the name of the output type, so that `this` becomes `That`.

Comment: @stella Hey, just checking if this is resolved

Answer (score 3):

Mapping a collection *can* result in the same collection (only parameterized with a different type), but it doesn't *have to* be so. It can result in a completely different collection. For example,

```
val myMap = Map("firstName" -> "foo", "lastName" -> "bar") 
val result = myMap map (_._1.length)
```

We started from `Map[String, String]` and ended up with `Iterable[Int]`. This is why `Traversable`s (note that `Traversable` is an "abstract trait" and `TraversableLike` is an "implementation trait") have this implicit builder called `CanBuildFrom`. `Option` is not a `Traversable` and doesn't need all this conversion machinery - we know that mapping an `Option` always results in an `Option`.

When performing `map` on `Traversable`s, compiler will find a corresponding value of type `CanBuildFrom` in a companion object (for example, [here's](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$@canBuildFrom[A]:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.List.Coll,A,List[A]]) the one for List). If it doesn't find any, it will go one level above, etc. Check out the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) (find "The CanBuildFrom trait" on page and start from there).

Answer (score 2):

You can read about the architecture of these collections [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html). I think it is used for knowing the correct return type of the operation. For example, when you call `toSet` on a `List`, an implicit `CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, Seq[A]]` must be in scope...