# Why does this Iterable produce a Set after mapping?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, iterator, iterable

In the sample code below, **why does the Iterable[String] `test1` produce a Set after mapping?**

```
val foo = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 1)
val test1: Iterable[String] = foo.keys
val test2: Iterator[String] = foo.keys.toIterator

println(test1.map(foo).size) // 1
println(test2.map(foo).size) // 2
```

I was puzzled by this because its entirely counter-intuitive when reading the code. Even though `foo.keys` just returns an Iterable, it creates a Set when calling `map`, as the reflection code shows:

```
println(test1.map(foo).getClass.getName) // immutable.Set.Set1
println(test2.map(foo).getClass.getName) // Iterator$$anon$11
```

How does the standard library determine that it should create an `immutable.Set` here, even though the inferred type of the collection is just `Iterable[String]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excavating Kolmar's comment that, although an implicit argument is in play that determines how the result collection is built, in this case the source collection is simply queried for the builder to use.

`Iterable.map`:

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Iterable[A], B, That]): That
```

Implicit scope includes types related to the type args, including `Iterable` and `Int`.

`Iterable` defines a "generic" `CanBuildFrom` that invokes `genericBuilder` on the source collection. That's how the result type is tied to the source.

Conversely, the result collection is divorced from the source by taking a `CanBuildFrom[From = Nothing, _, _]`. This is how `cc.to[Set]` is expressed, where a `Set` is built without regard for the source collection `cc`. For operations such as `map`, the method `collection.breakOut` provides such a `CanBuildFrom`, where the result type can be usefully inferred.

You can inject an arbitrary `CanBuildFrom` for the desired behavior:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 1)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 1)

scala> val k = m.keys
k: Iterable[String] = Set(a, b)

scala> import collection.{generic, mutable}, generic.{CanBuildFrom => CBF}, mutable.ListBuffer
import collection.{generic, mutable}
import generic.{CanBuildFrom=>CBF}
import mutable.ListBuffer

scala>   implicit def `as list`: CBF[Iterable[_], Int, List[Int]] =
     |     new CBF[Iterable[_], Int, List[Int]] {
     |       def apply() = new ListBuffer[Int]
     |       def apply(from: Iterable[_]) = apply()
     |     }
as$u0020list: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Iterable[_],Int,List[Int]]

scala> k.map(m)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1)
```

Worth adding that completion can show types as of 2.11.8:

```
scala> k.map(m) //print<tab>

$line4.$read.$iw.$iw.k.map[Int, Iterable[Int]]($line3.$read.$iw.$iw.m)(scala.collection.Iterable.canBuildFrom[Int]) // : Iterable[Int]
```

Using `breakOut`:

```
scala> k.map(m)(collection.breakOut)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 1)

scala> k.map(m)(collection.breakOut) //print

$line4.$read.$iw.$iw.k.map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]]($line3.$read.$iw.$iw.m)(scala.collection.`package`.breakOut[Any, Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]](scala.Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[Int])) // : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
```

As shown, it actually picks up the `CanBuildFrom` intended for operations such as:

```
scala> "abc".map(_ + 1)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(98, 99, 100)

scala> "abc".map(_ + 1) //print

scala.Predef.augmentString("abc").map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]](((x$1: Char) => x$1.+(1)))(scala.Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[Int]) // : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
```

Compare:

```
scala> k.map(m)(collection.breakOut) : List[Int] //print

(($line6.$read.$iw.$iw.k.map[Int, List[Int]]($line5.$read.$iw.$iw.m)(scala.collection.`package`.breakOut[Iterable[String], Int, List[Int]](scala.collection.immutable.List.canBuildFrom[Int]))): scala.`package`.List[scala.Int]) // : List[Int]
```

The [canonical Q&A on breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

Comment: Also worth adding that the common mechanism to override tying the type to the source is to use `scala.collection.breakOut`. So `foo.keys.map(foo)(collection.breakOut)` will result in `Vector(1, 1): scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]`. This also allows type inference from the result, so `val l: List[Int] = foo.keys.map(foo)(collection.breakOut)` will result in a runtime `List(1, 1)`.

Comment: There's also a community answer option, but I don't know the keystrokes offhand. Have to rush off at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

`foo.keys` returns a `Set` (despite its return type being more general) and calling map on a `Set` produces another `Set`. The inferred or compile time type is not always the most precise.

You can see that the `keys` method on a `Set` returns a `Set` even though the return *type* is `Iterable[A]`:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 2).keys
res0: Iterable[Int] = Set(1)
```

Comment: If this were the case, it wouldn't have puzzled me. But in fact: 
foo.keySet returns a Set.
foo.keys returns an Iterable.

Comment: @Chris `Set` is a subclass of `Iterable`, so `Map.keys` just calls `keySet` and returns the `Set` as an `Iterable`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L192

Comment: I still didn't know why `set.map` results in a set. Like the OP, I thought the mechanism was encoded in static types.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky implicit magic. Simplified answer: there exists `CanBuildFrom` value, that is passed in implicit scope. When compiler is searching for most common type, it looks for implicits in arguments' scope.

In your example, compiler is able to figure out that most common type for `foo.keys` is `Set`. This sounds reasonable: Set can be viewed as Map with absent values (also java's HashMap/HashSet do that). When you convert to iterable, implicits are lost, and `Set` is gone (as side note, those `CanBuildFrom` hacks are not robust, and might get gone in future, because they really complicate extending of existing collections, you might also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728140/6345611) answer and comments).

Scala shares Java's concept of "de-jure and de-facto types". "de-jure" is one declared in method definition, but "de-facto" might be one of inheritors. That's why, for example, you see `Map.keys` type as `Iterable`, when de-facto it is `Set` (produced from `Map.keySet`, which has `Set` de-jure type).

Last, `1` in first println is because in underlying map `foo` all values are the same, and `Set(1,1)` becomes `Set(1)`.

Comment: This answer is a bit wrong. It's not implicit magic, more like the usual OOP polymorphism magic. The compiler can't figure that `foo.keys` is a `Set`. It uses `CanBuildFrom` from an `Iterable`: `Iterable.canBuildFrom`, but that `canBuildFrom` calls `genericBuilder` on the actual collection object, and since, yes, this is a `Set` at runtime, this results in `Set.newBuilder` being used.

Comment: Also, I don't think there are any plans to have CBFs gone. The answer you have linked to doesn't support that claim. It says that they should be hidden in the docs by default, and that has already been implemented for a long time.

Comment: @Kolmar my guess about "no CBF" is based on recent discussion about new collections' proposal. That's why "might get gone".

Comment: Is it this proposal https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/818 ? That's interesting, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, this proposal.