# Understanding flatMap declaration in List

Tags: scala, collections, implicit

I just looked at the `List.flatMap` declaration and was kind of surprised by this.

```
final override def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])
                 (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

Where `object List` defines:

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, List[A]] =
    ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]
```

So, if we invoke `flatMap` on a `List` we will get the `List` and I don't see any point in `That` type if it will always be deduced to `List[B]` (because of the `implicit`).

Comment: that `implicit` can be overridden with a more local one, that builds to, let's say, a `Vector`, or explicitly passed as a parameter

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1728140/5344058 for an example of when it's useful to have `That` being a different type compared to the original collection

Comment: Have you ever seen a `collection.breakout` with flatMap or Map... that is one example of overriding this implicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, if we invoke `flatMap` on a `List[A]` we will get the `List[A]` and I don't
>   see any point in `That` type if it will always be deduced to `List[B]`

One thing you're missing is that `flatMap` isn't actually defined on `List[+A]`. It is inherited from `TraversableLike`, which is a trait used by most of Scalas collections. Each of them can supply the implicit `CanBuildFrom` which may be overridden to supply a different resulting collection.

If you want a little taste of what you can do with a custom `CanBuildFrom`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.{List, Vector}

implicit val listToVectorCBF = new CanBuildFrom[List[Int], Int, Vector[Int]] {
  override def apply(from: List[Int]): mutable.Builder[Int, Vector[Int]] = this.apply()
  override def apply(): mutable.Builder[Int, Vector[Int]] = Vector.newBuilder
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> List(1,2,3).flatMap(List(_))
res6: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: But can I supply my own `CanBuildFrom` in order to get something that is not even a Seq?

Comment: @user3663882 Nothing is stopping you from supplying your own. It makes it easier for derived classes to simply provide their own CBF implicit instead of re-implementing the method.

Comment: @user3663882 I've added a little example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Well... That `implicit CanBuildFrom` can be used to directly build different type of structure instead of `List` and thus saving one extra step. lets look at following example,

```
val list = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))

// now if we do a flatmap withtout overriding the implicit CanBuildFrom
val newList = list.flatMap(l => l.map(i => (i,i)))

// new list will be a List[(Int, Int)]
// but what if you wanted a map

val newMap = newList.toMap

// But you actually needed to traverse the list twice in this case

// But we can avoid the second traversal if we chose to override the implicit
val newMap2 = list.flatMap(l => l.map(i => (i,i)))(collection.breakout)
```